# Convert Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens from Silverlight to WPF

Tags: caliburn.micro

How to convert caliburnmicro hello screen sample from silverlight to wpf?

Is there any clue that I should remove from the sample project?

Why the author didn't provide wpf sample?

Answer (score -2):

There is a link that post by BladeWise that did a conversion, the link is still good...
http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/238918

as to the state of why he did the Silverlight because at the time it was a proof of concept and it served the purpose of showing cross platform development, as I have looked at the sample myself a minor amount of work was necessary to do the conversion.  A major adjustment to the code was necessary with respect to the one control to make the transition work, to avoid the transition issues altogether was to just use a contentcontrol

updated--

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: so now you can go and look for yourself since the link does actually work, just checked myself..  thanks for the down vote.

Comment: I did not downvote you, my comment is a moderation comment if you will read it again.

Comment: this is the CM 2.0.2.0 version of the conversion made by mvermef https://cmhelloscreenswpf.codeplex.com/